# A "Dusty" aftertaste in my beer

Tags: off-flavor, aftertaste

I have recently made a batch of pale ale malt and willamette SmaSh,
I used a BIAB setup and "no chill"-ed it in a cube over night.
I'm overall pleased with the final prodect, however it has a distinct aftertaste I can only describe as "dusty".
It should be noted that I could not squeeze the air completelty out of my cube,

I left the beer in primery for about a week after fermantation was done(I wasn't sure), fermentaition temprature wast completely stable and propebly neared 30C at times,
Also the beer has developed a "chill haze".
While all of those are problems I intend to fix in my next batch I'm wondering if there is a direct cuse for this specific aftertaste that I should target first?

---

Here is my recipe:

HOME BREW RECIPE:
Title: Smash

Brew Method: BIAB
Style Name: American Pale Ale
Boil Time: 60 min
Batch Size: 11 liters (fermentor volume)
Boil Size: 15 liters
Boil Gravity: 1.036
Efficiency: 50% (brew house)
No Chill: 20 minute extended hop boil time

STATS:
Original Gravity: 1.054
Final Gravity: 1.020
ABV (standard): 4.93%
IBU (tinseth): 31.99
SRM (morey): 4.96

FERMENTABLES:
3.3 kg - German - Pale Ale (100%)

HOPS:
15 g - Willamette, Type: Pellet, AA: 4.5, Use: Boil for 60 min, IBU: 18.66
15 g - Willamette, Type: Leaf/Whole, AA: 4.5, Use: Boil for 15 min, IBU: 13.33

MASH GUIDELINES:
1) Infusion, Temp: 72 C, Time: 60 min, Amount: 14 L

YEAST:
Danstar - Nottingham Ale Yeast
Starter: No
Form: Dry
Attenuation (avg): 77%
Flocculation: High
Optimum Temp: 13.89 - 21.11 C
Fermentation Temp: 21 C
Pitch Rate: 0.35 (M cells / ml / deg P)

PRIMING:
Method: Corn sugar
Amount: 60g
CO2 Level: 2.2 Volumes

Generated by Brewer's Friend - https://www.brewersfriend.com/
Date: 2018-08-16 16:22 UTC 
Recipe Last Updated: 2018-07-19 18:08 UTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I chased a similar off flavor for years before I finally concluded it was coming from the US-05 yeast I was using. I'm not sure everyone can taste it, but it was very offensive to me. Dusty was the exact word I used to describe it. It was strongest in the finish of the first sip, and it grew weaker as I continued to drink. It wasn't every batch I brewed with US-05, maybe one out of every four.

There was a window where I used WLP090 instead, and I never got the off flavor then. I switched to Mangrove Jack's M36 about a year ago and haven't had the off flavor since. I tried everything I could think of, but it only went away when I switched to a different yeast.

That said, I see you used Nottingham. I have never used that strain so I can't say from personal experience that it would be the culprit here. I have also never heard of anyone else having this problem with US-05. So all I have is one anecdote to offer.

Answer (score 2):

The only defect flavor I could relate to "Dusty" would be from oxidation. Most recognize it more as a wet cardboard flavor but I too have experienced it as a something more similar to opening an old dusty book if you were to translate a smell to a taste.

Comment: I think I can imagine the flavor you are talking about but I don't think that's my case. If you ever been outside during a sand storm or a windy day at a desert, than the flavor you get in your mouth afterward is what I'm experiencing with my beer